# Como contar a partir do "1" em vez de "0" em um array do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, node.js

Estou estudando vetores e utilizei carros e vagas em estacionamento de exemplo.

Porém o `console.log` começa a contar a partir do `0` e eu queria que ele contasse a partir do `1` e mesmo assim apresentasse 4 vagas "1, 2 , 3, 4".

Código:

```js
let vagas = ['Audi', 'HB20', 'Lamborghini', 'Maserati']

console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`)

for (let lugar in vagas) {
    console.log(`na vaga ${lugar} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]}`)
}
```

A saída segue:

```
na vaga 0 está o Automóvel Audi
na vaga 1 está o Automóvel HB20
na vaga 2 está o Automóvel Lamborghini
na vaga 3 está o Automóvel Maserati
```

Queria que contasse "1 ,2 ,3 ,4".

Comment: PS: *for...in não deve ser usado para iteração em uma Array onde a ordem é importante, visto que ele o itera em uma ordem arbitrária*  - fonte: [MDN Web Docs | for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somando 1, só isso. Porque você não quer contar partindo do 1, quer apenas que apresente o elemento como sendo vaga 1.

```js
let vagas = ['Audi', 'HB20', 'Lamborghini', 'Maserati'];
console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`);
for (let lugar in vagas) console.log(`na vaga ${parseInt(lugar) + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]}`);
```

Outra forma é usar um `for` bruto, que eu acho mais adequado para seu caso:

```js
let vagas = ['Audi', 'HB20', 'Lamborghini', 'Maserati'];
console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`);
for (let i = 0; i < vagas.length; i++) console.log(`na vaga ${i + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[i]}`);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/CountFor.js).

Mais uma possibilidade é criar um *array* esparso dizendo explicitamente quais são as chaves, mas isso é um pouco perigoso e tem que saber administrar, por exemplo, tem que contar quantos elementos tem em vez de pegar o tamanho:

```js
let vagas = {1 : 'Audi', 2 : 'HB20', 3 : 'Lamborghini', 4 : 'Maserati'};
console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${Object.keys(vagas).length} vagas`);
for (let lugar in vagas) console.log(`na vaga ${lugar} está o Automóvel ${vagas[lugar]}`);
```

Comment: Ainda tem a possibilidade de usar a função forEach(), no caso resultaria em algo dessa maneira: `vagas.forEach((vaga, lugar) => console.log(\`Na vaga ${lugar + 1} está o Automóvel ${vaga}\`))`;

Answer (score 5):

Não utilize o `for..in`, que deve ser usado para iterar sobre as *chaves enumeráveis* de um objeto. Utilize um `for` normal e, no momento de imprimir, some 1 ao contador (`i`).

Algo assim:

```js
let vagas = ['Audi', 'HB20', 'Lamborghini', 'Maserati'];

console.log(`No estacionamento tem ${vagas.length} vagas`);

for (let i = 0; i < vagas.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Na vaga ${i + 1} está o Automóvel ${vagas[i]}`);
}
```

Os arrays em JavaScript são objetos que possuem elementos enumeráveis, sempre iniciando a partir do índice zero. Não tente modificar esse comportamento padrão da linguagem porque será gambiarra. Se necessário iniciar a *exibição* a partir de 1, faça-o somente no momento de exibir.

Comment: Certo, "Se necessário iniciar a exibição a partir de 1, faça-o somente no momento de exibir" como?

Comment: Somando no momento de exibição, conforme fiz no código anterior. Note que só somei no momento de imprimir (logo no `console.log`).

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim, ordene a partir do 1 e pronto.

```
var let = [ 
{ nome: 'Audi', num: 1     },
{ nome: 'HB20', num: 2     },
{ nome: 'Lamborghini', num: 3    },
{ nome: 'Maserati', num: 4    }
];

for (let i = 1; i < let.length; i++) {
console.log(`Na vaga ${i} está o Automóvel ${let[i]}`);
}
```